# How to slide to next div after scroll down a little like the iphone 5c page?

Tags: jquery, scroll, slide, effect

I found the iphone 5C introduction page scrolling effect is quite interesting .
It will automatically snap to the top of the next content box after finish scrolling the current box.

http://www.apple.com/hk/iphone-5c/

I tried to find the jquery plugin involved for an hour but failed.
Please tell me how to make that effect or where to find a tutorial about that.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are searching for parallax effect

Comment: I am not talking on the flowing of the phones image.
I am talking about the scroll snapping effect.
anyway thanks for your reply.:)

Comment: I find this "effect" to be incredibly irritating. It takes away my browser's scroll bar (which is easy to grab with the mouse) in favor of tiny little dots.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with the JQuery Mousewheel Plugin and scrollTo:

```
var isScrolling = false;

$('.onepager').mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
    if (!isScrolling) {
        isScrolling = true;
        if (delta < 0) {
            if ($next = $('#navbox').find('.active').next('li').children('a').attr('href')) {
                $('.onepager').scrollTo($next, {
                    offset: -120,
                    duration: 1000,
                    onAfter: function () {
                        isScrolling = false;
                    }
                });
            } else
                isScrolling = false;

        }
        else if (delta > 0) {
            if ($prev = $('#navbox').find('.active').prev('li').children('a').attr('href')) {
                $('.onepager').scrollTo($prev, {
                    offset: -120,
                    duration: 1000,
                    onAfter: function () {
                        isScrolling = false;
                    }
                });
            } else
                isScrolling = false;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you have a demo of this? I like this effect and want to see how it looks compared to apples web page